# Set App Service application setting from Azure DevOps yaml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

We are using AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 for deploying our web app into an Azure App Service via a `yaml` file. So far, so good.

Now we want to set few settings from yaml, rather than using a .json or .xml file

Currently we do it manually through the Azure Portal -> App Services -> Configuration -> Application Settings (see screenshot below)

How we can do it programmatically from a yaml pipeline?

[image: Azure portal App Service settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be easy to keep variables directly in YAML file especially in the same file as pipeline and set configuration of App Service. For sure you should use [Azure App Service Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-settings?view=azure-devops) task:

```yaml
- task: AzureAppServiceSettings@0
  displayName: Azure App Service Settings
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
    appName: $(WebApp_Name)
   # To deploy the settings on a slot, provide slot name as below. By default, the settings would be applied to the actual Web App (Production slot)
   # slotName: staging
    appSettings: |
      [
        {
          "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
          "value": "$(Key)",
          "slotSetting": false
        },
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME",
          "value": "$(DB_Name)", 
          "slotSetting": false
        }
      ]
    generalSettings: |
      [
        {
          "name": "WEBAPP_NAME",
          "value": "$(WebApp_Name)",
          "slotSetting": false
        },
        {
          "name": "WEBAPP_PLAN_NAME",
          "value": "$(WebApp_PlanName)",
          "slotSetting": false
        }
      ]
    connectionStrings: |
      [
        {
          "name": "MysqlCredentials",
          "value": "$(MySQl_ConnectionString)",
          "type": "MySql",
          "slotSetting": false
        }
      ]
```

And you can use variables from pipeline (or variable group) to feed this task or read them from another file and set variables programitacally in powershell task using this syntax:

```bsh
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"
```

But please consider keeping your settings in Azure Key Vault. In this way you can feed your variable group and keep configuration in safe place. Please check this [link](https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Access-Azure-Key-Vault-secrets-in-the-Azure-DevOps-Release-Pipelines/).

Answer (score 3):

You can add a new [App Settings task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-settings?view=azure-devops) in the pipelines,

Click **`+`** sign on the pipeline (add new task) and choose **`'Azure App Service Settings'`** and on App Settings for the Task, add the settings you need

[image]