# Azure devops add single configuration application setting to function app using YAML without modifying existing configuration

Tags: azure, yaml

I need to add single application setting without modifying existing configuration for function app, I found this question [Set App Service application setting from Azure DevOps yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493669/set-app-service-application-setting-from-azure-devops-yaml) but looking at the solution (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-settings?view=azure-devops) it looks like this will overwrite settings rather than adding new setting, I would like to just pass key and value to be added rather than writing whole appconfig.

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72946083/4167200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soulution for me was to use command from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-appsettings-set

```
az webapp config appsettings set -g GRPNAME -n APPNAME --settings dummy1=dummy1value
```